# Use of unassigned local variable 'accessor

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Could someone please help me to spot whats wrong here?

```
accessor.Dispose();
```

Causes compiler error but only in the Read method. Write compiles fine without Read so im puzzled...

```
    public bool Read(ref byte[] bytes)
    {
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor;
        Lock.WaitOne();
        try
        {                
            accessor = Mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, DataLength);
            bytes = new byte[DataLength];
            accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, DataLength);                
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            accessor.Dispose();
            Lock.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Write(byte[] bytes)
    {
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor;
        Lock.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            DataLength = bytes.Length;
            accessor = Mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, bytes.Length);
            accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
            Lock.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Just a note:  You are calling your class's `Dispose()` method in your `Write` method, instead of `accessor.Dispose();`.  This may lead to unintended behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for, an exception to be throw inside the `try` and before `accessor` is assigned a value.  Some ways this could happen:

1. A thread abort exception
2. An out of memory exception allocating the new object
3. An exception in the constructor of the object you're assigning to it.

As for what to do about it; there are two simple enough options:

1. Use a `using` for that variable so that the compiler can do all of the work for you.
2. Initialize `accessor` to `null`, and dispose of it only if it's non-null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the variable, but it's possible for it to fail to be initialized if there were an exception thrown.

I would refactor this to use a `using` block instead:

```
public bool Read(ref byte[] bytes)
{
    Lock.WaitOne();
    try
    {                
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = Mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, DataLength))
        {
            bytes = new byte[DataLength];
            accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, DataLength);                
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Lock.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to initialize to `null` inline, then check for `null` prior to the call to `Dispose`, but that would require more code, where as a using block simplifies the code overall.

Comment: So the catch in this example will be executed even if an exception occurs in the using block?

Answer (score 1):

You should have gotten the same error in both the `Read` and `Write` method, but the code in the `Write` method is wrong, so it avoids the error.

In `Write` you have:

```
    finally
    {
        Dispose();
        Lock.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

but that should have been:

```
    finally
    {
        accessor.Dispose();
        Lock.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

The compiler error is because it's possible to end up in the `finally` block without a value being assigned to `accessor`. That would happen if you get an exception while creating the object that you assign to the varialble.

To fix the compiler error, you can set a `null` value to the `accessor` variable before the `try` block:

```
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = null;
```

Then in the `finally` block you check if you got an actual object to dispose:

```
    finally
    {
        if (accessor != null) {
            accessor.Dispose();
        }
        Lock.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

e only decalred the variable `MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor;` And then trying to use it in finally block of Read. So you get compiler error.u

But in write you are just calling dispose (not accessor.Dispose()) so no error there. Might be a typing mistake??

You need to initialize accessor before finally block. Might need to correct finally of write.

Read:

```
finally
        {
            accessor.Dispose();
            Lock.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Write:

```
 finally
        {
            Dispose();
            Lock.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```